# How to find a word from a sentence using php case insensitive?

Tags: php

I am having difficulty to find a word from a sentence. Using the code below it should return false but its returning true. Can anyone help me, please?

```
 if(stristr('I live in a farmhouse','farm'))
    {
       echo 'true';
    }
    else
    {
       echo 'false';
    }
```

Comment: And why should it return false?

Comment: because farm word is not in the sentence but code return true by finding farmhouse.

Comment: then search for `' farm '` with spaces. Computer cannot decide whether you find a word or just a sequence of chars.

Comment: `farm` is the needle and it was found so behavior is correct. You need a different function, regex solution below should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this mission a Regular Expression (regexp) would come handy. There is `\b` separator which means "word boundry". So let's see how it goes:
(The `i` at the end means insensitive)

```
if (preg_match('/\bfarm\b/i', 'I live in a farmhouse')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: thanks, what if (preg_match('/\bcat\b/i', 'I live with The Cat')); in this situation it should return true but getting false

Comment: You had a typo, it should work `preg_match('/\bcat\b/i', 'I live with The Cat')`